# Pause/Suspend guest in KVM without virsh and libvirtd

Tags: linux, virtualization, linux-kvm

I have installed KVM without libvirt/virsh and virtualmanager. 
Packages which installed are kvm qemu-kvm bridge-utils libguestfs-tools

How can I pause/suspend VM in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long searching and experiments, the best option for me became qemu monitor. See https://nico.schottelius.org/blog/control-and-shutdown-qemu-kvm-vm-via-unix-socket/ for more details regarding flexible management guest by using qemu monitor.